# Wagner's-Whitin Algorithm

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm having trouble in solving this problem dealing with the Wagner's-Whitin Algorithm, because the holding and ordering costs are not given, we only have the optimal costs from the beginning to each node, and the shortest path.
**(The answer is $2050)**

[image: Wagner's Whitin]

Comment: Does to optimal path show in which weeks we order (weeks 1, 2, 4 and 5)? Because then I would suspect the ordering costs in week 2 for satisfying the demand in weeks 2 and 3 to be 2550 and not 2050, since we do not order in week 3 and order again in week 4.